# FATAL Exception:java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android

I try to solve this problem but i don't find any solution so please help me to solve it.
1)My Package.java file:

```
b_indian=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_indian);
        b_classic=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_classic);
        b_royal=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_royal);
        t_pkg=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t_pkg);
        t_indian=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t_indian);
        t_classic=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t_classic);
        t_royal=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t_royal);

        b_indian.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Package.this,Indianpkg.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        b_classic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Package.this,Classicpkg.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        b_royal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Package.this,Royalpkg.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

2)activity_package.xml

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Package"
        android:id="@+id/t_pkg"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        style="@style/Title"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_weight="0.5">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/b_indian"

            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_margin="25dp"/>


</RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="INDIAN"
                android:id="@+id/t_indian"
                android:layout_margin="55dp"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                style="@style/SimpleText"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">


                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/b_classic"

                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="25dp" />


            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="CLASSIC"
                    android:layout_margin="50dp"
                    android:id="@+id/t_classic"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    style="@style/SimpleText"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">


                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/b_royal"

                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="25dp"/>



            </RelativeLayout>


            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:text="ROYAL"
                    android:layout_margin="55dp"
                    android:id="@+id/t_royal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    style="@style/SimpleText"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

This is my package file and i put same code to intent three different packages in that file but i intent only indian package and rest of two packages is not intent and i have error:FATAL Exception.
Following all files:
1)Indianpkg.java

```
b_i_venue=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i_venue);
        b_i_decor=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i_decor);
        b_i_caterer=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i_caterer);
        b_i_photo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i_photo);
        b_i_mehandi=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i_mehandi);
        b_i_dj=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i_dj);
        t1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t1);

        b_i_venue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Indianpkg.this,Indian_venue.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        b_i_decor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Indianpkg.this,Indian_decoration.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        b_i_caterer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Indianpkg.this,Indian_decoration.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        b_i_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Indianpkg.this,Indian_caterer.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        b_i_mehandi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Indianpkg.this,Indian_mehandi.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        b_i_dj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Indianpkg.this,Indian_dj.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

2)activity_indianpkg.xml

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=" Indian Wedding"
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        style="@style/Title"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/b_i_venue"
                    android:background="@drawable/i_venue"
                    android:text="Venue"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    style="@style/Title"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/b_i_decor"
                    android:background="@drawable/i_decoration"
                    android:text="Decoration"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    style="@style/Title"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/b_i_caterer"
                    android:text="Caterer"
                    android:background="@drawable/i_caterer"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    style="@style/Title"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/b_i_photo"
                    android:text="Photography"
                    android:background="@drawable/i_photography"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    style="@style/Title"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/b_i_mehandi"
                    android:text="Mehandi"
                    android:background="@drawable/i_mahendi"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    style="@style/Title"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/b_i_dj"
                    android:text="DJ"
                    android:background="@drawable/i_dj"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    style="@style/Title"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

Above code is run succesfully. But below code is also same but still not run and give FATAL Exception.

3)Classic.java

```
b_c_venue=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i_venue);
        b_c_decor=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i_decor);
        b_c_caterer=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i_caterer);
        b_c_photo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i_photo);
        b_c_mehandi=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i_mehandi);
        b_c_dj=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_i_dj);
        t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t2);

        b_c_venue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Classicpkg.this,Classic_venue.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        b_c_decor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Classicpkg.this,Classic_decoration.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        b_c_caterer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Classicpkg.this,Classic_caterer.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        b_c_photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Classicpkg.this,Classic_photography.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        b_c_mehandi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Classicpkg.this,Classic_mehandi.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        b_c_dj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(Classicpkg.this,Classic_dj.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

4)activity_classic.xml

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text=" Classic Wedding"
        android:id="@+id/t2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        style="@style/Title"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/b_c_venue"
                    android:background="@drawable/i_venue"
                    android:text="Venue"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    style="@style/Title"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/b_c_decor"
                    android:background="@drawable/i_decoration"
                    android:text="Decoration"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    style="@style/Title"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/b_c_caterer"
                    android:text="Caterer"
                    android:background="@drawable/i_caterer"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    style="@style/Title"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/b_c_photo"
                    android:text="Photography"
                    android:background="@drawable/i_photography"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    style="@style/Title"/>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:layout_weight="0.5">
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/b_c_mehandi"
                    android:text="Mehandi"
                    android:background="@drawable/i_mahendi"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    style="@style/Title"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.5">
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/b_c_dj"
                    android:text="DJ"
                    android:background="@drawable/i_dj"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    style="@style/Title"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
        </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aU0B.png)

Comment: kindly provide logcat .

Comment: have you declare your `Activity` in `manifest.xml` file ??

Comment: Please do not post your **whole** project. Just post the important parts of files. Also the most important thing - error logcat.

Comment: you did not post the only thing that will mostly help you LOGCAT!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you haven't add activity class in AndroidMaifest.xml
if you don't!

Add Activity to your AndroidMaifest.xml

like this

```
        <activity
           android:name=".Classic"
           android:label="your_activity_label">
        </activity>
```

Then Edit Code in Classic.java

```
    b_c_venue=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_c_venue);
    b_c_decor=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_c_decor);
    b_c_caterer=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_c_caterer);
    b_c_photo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_c_photo);
    b_c_mehandi=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_c_mehandi);
    b_c_dj=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_c_dj);
    t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ids are wrong for your classic view, change ...*i*... for ....*c*... in your Classic Activity, like this:

```
b_c_venue=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b_c_venue);
```